# Feasible region of some linear inequalities

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

Suppose that we have $n$ inequalities of this type
$$
a_1\leq x_1+y\leq b_1\\
a_2\leq x_2+y\leq b_2\\
\vdots\\
a_n\leq x_n+y\leq b_n\\
$$
where $a_1,...,a_n$ and $b_1,...,b_n$ are finite real numbers; $x_1,..., x_n, y$ are unknowns.

Let $\Theta\equiv \{(x_1,...,x_n,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}: \text{ the inequalities above are satisfied}\}$.

**Claim:** $\Theta$ is not bounded.

Is this claim correct and, if yes, how can we show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is an admissible point $(x_1,x_2,\cdots x_n,y)$ then all points $(x_1+z,x_2+z,\cdots x_n+z,y-z)$ are admissible.

(The admissible set is an oblique [hyper]prism with a [hyper]rectangular base.)